# How do I convince tocloft to put the word 'Figura' ahead of entries in my List of Figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, tocloft

How to customize list of figures, adding word FIGURA to appears in the table of contents? I changed `\newcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figura }`, but in the summary, it's not linked (`hyperref`). How to solve it?

```
\renewcommand*{\l@figure}[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@lofdepth >\z@
    \vskip \cftbeforefigskip
    {\leftskip \cftfigindent\relax
     \rightskip \@tocrmarg
     \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent \cftfigindent\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima \cftfignumwidth\relax
     \let\@cftbsnum \cftfigpresnum
     \let\@cftasnum \cftfigaftersnum
     \let\@cftasnumb \cftfigaftersnumb
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {\cftfigfont #1}\nobreak
     \cftfigfillnum{#2}}
   \fi
  }
\newlength{\cftbeforefigskip}
  \setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{\z@ \@plus.2\p@}
\newlength{\cftfigindent}
  \setlength{\cftfigindent}{1.5em}
\newlength{\cftfignumwidth}
  \setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.3em}
\newcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figura }
\newcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{}
\newcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{}
\newcommand{\cftfigaftersnumb}{}
\newcommand{\cftfigleader}{\normalfont\cftdotfill{\cftfigdotsep}}
\newcommand{\cftfigdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\newcommand{\cftfigpagefont}{\normalfont}
\newcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{}
\newcommand{\cftfigfillnum}[1]{%
  {\cftfigleader}\nobreak
  \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\cftfigpagefont #1}\cftfigafterpnum\par}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `beamer`?

Comment: @Martin It can't really be for beamer, so I retagged it

Comment: Please make sure that the next time you ask a question you provide a fully working example. From what you show in your code it is impossible to reproduce your problem. A good question is hard to ask but always the basis to a good answer.

Answer (score 9):

(Assuming the real question is "how do I convince tocloft to put the word 'Figura' ahead of entries in my List of Figures?")

`\cftfigfont` is for setting the font to typeset the List of Figures entries. `\cftfigpresnum` is for adding arbitrary text to the beginning on the entries. Both of these are described in section 2.3 of [the tocloft manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf). You'll probably also need to increase the `\cftfignumwidth` length to accommodate your extra text. Try something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figura }
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{5em}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering (Figure goes here)
\caption{The first figure}
\label{fig:first}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering (Figure goes here)
\caption{The second figure}
\label{fig:second}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]